# Service builder doesn't build services for new entities added Liferay

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I have a service builder and there are few entitties.
Now when I try to add more entities to the service builder and try to build services, the services for this new entity are not getting created.

What should possibly be the problem and how to tackle it?

Another problem that I am facing is the newly created portlets are not shown in the control panel.
Earlier i never had any such problems.

Don't know what has happned. I tried restarting the server,refreshing workspace but no use.

EDITED:

CONSOLE OUTPUT

```
[Console output redirected to file:D:\test\MIS\.metadata\.plugins\com.liferay.ide.eclipse.sdk\sdk.log]
Buildfile: D:\MIS_Portal\liferay-plugins-sdk-6.1.1\portlets\MISPortal-portlet\build.xml
build-service:
     [echo] Loading jar:file:/D:/TEST_MIS_Portal/liferay-portal-6.1.1-ce-ga2/totestt-7.0.27/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/portal-impl.jar!/system.properties
     [echo] Apr 25, 2013 10:34:16 AM com.liferay.portal.kernel.log.Jdk14LogImpl info
     [echo] INFO: Global shared lib directory /D:/TEST_MIS_Portal/liferay-plugins-sdk-6.1.1/lib/
     [echo] Apr 25, 2013 10:34:16 AM com.liferay.portal.kernel.log.Jdk14LogImpl info
     [echo] INFO: Global lib directory /D:/TEST_MIS_Portal/liferay-portal-6.1.1-ce-ga2/totestt-7.0.27/lib/ext/
     [echo] Apr 25, 2013 10:34:16 AM com.liferay.portal.kernel.log.Jdk14LogImpl info
     [echo] INFO: Portal lib directory /D:/TEST_MIS_Portal/liferay-portal-6.1.1-ce-ga2/totestt-7.0.27/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/
     [echo] Apr 25, 2013 10:34:17 AM com.liferay.portal.kernel.log.Jdk14LogImpl info
     [echo] INFO: Properties for portal loaded from [file:/D:/TEST_MIS_Portal/liferay-portal-6.1.1-ce-ga2/totestt-7.0.27/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/classes/portal-ext.properties, jar:file:/D:/TEST_MIS_Portal/liferay-portal-6.1.1-ce-ga2/totestt-7.0.27/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/portal-impl.jar!/com/liferay/portal/tools/dependencies/portal-tools.properties, jar:file:/D:/TEST_MIS_Portal/liferay-portal-6.1.1-ce-ga2/totestt-7.0.27/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/portal-impl.jar!/portal.properties]
     [echo] Loading jar:file:/D:/TEST_MIS_Portal/liferay-portal-6.1.1-ce-ga2/totestt-7.0.27/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/portal-impl.jar!/portal.properties
     [echo] Loading jar:file:/D:/TEST_MIS_Portal/liferay-portal-6.1.1-ce-ga2/totestt-7.0.27/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/portal-impl.jar!/com/liferay/portal/tools/dependencies/portal-tools.properties
     [echo] Loading file:/D:/TEST_MIS_Portal/liferay-portal-6.1.1-ce-ga2/totestt-7.0.27/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/classes/portal-ext.properties
     [echo] java.lang.RuntimeException: Column employerCity not found
     [echo]     at com.liferay.portal.tools.servicebuilder.Entity.getColumn(Entity.java:62)
     [echo]     at com.liferay.portal.tools.servicebuilder.ServiceBuilder._parseEntity(ServiceBuilder.java:4783)
     [echo]     at com.liferay.portal.tools.servicebuilder.ServiceBuilder.<init>(ServiceBuilder.java:636)
     [echo]     at com.liferay.portal.tools.servicebuilder.ServiceBuilder.main(ServiceBuilder.java:151)
    [mkdir] Created dir: D:\TEST_MIS_Portal\liferay-plugins-sdk-6.1.1\portlets\MISMISPortal-portlet\docroot\WEB-INF\service-classes
compile-java:
     [copy] Copied 9 empty directories to 9 empty directories under D:\TEST_MIS_Portal\liferay-plugins-sdk-6.1.1\portlets\MISMISPortal-portlet\docroot\WEB-INF\service-classes
    [javac] Compiling 86 source files to D:\TEST_MIS_Portal\liferay-plugins-sdk-6.1.1\portlets\MISMISPortal-portlet\docroot\WEB-INF\service-classes
      [zip] Building zip: D:\TEST_MIS_Portal\liferay-plugins-sdk-6.1.1\portlets\MISMISPortal-portlet\docroot\WEB-INF\lib\MISMISPortal-portlet-service.jar
   [delete] Deleting directory D:\TEST_MIS_Portal\liferay-plugins-sdk-6.1.1\portlets\MISMISPortal-portlet\docroot\WEB-INF\service-classes
BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 7 seconds
```

Comment: are u getting any errors in the ant-console when u build the services?

Comment: @Prakash K:
I have added The console output in the EDITED section in the question.I get that console output after I build services.
One suggestion which I got in another forum in liferay is to delete all service classes (after taking backup of **LocalServiceImpl class) and build the services again

Comment: what do you mean by 'the services for this new entity are not getting created' ? the **LocalServiceImpl Classes are not created ? It might be a nice idea to give us your services.xml file too

Comment: @yannicuLar:

What I mean is I had some entities say A,B,C,D in my service.xml file and built services. I got all the service classes after building services. Next Now when I try to add another entity say E in the service.xml file and try to build services, I get the console output  which I have posted in the EDITED section of this ques. But no service classes are generated for entity E. This has been happening for quite sometime.

Comment: in your entity declaration, in service.xml, there are attributes like 'local-service', 'remote-service', 'cache-enabled' etc. You're also referring somewhere on a column named 'employerCity'. That's why you should post us your .xml file

Comment: I would say check where you are declaring the `employerCity` in `service.xml`, that might be the problem `java.lang.RuntimeException: Column employerCity not found`, may be you are referencing this column incorrectly in some entity or check the spelling of the column.

Comment: @ Advaita Gosvami:
Thanks Advaita.. :) I got it working

Comment: I am glad it did. Have converted the comment into answer, so that we can close this question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say check where you are declaring the `employerCity` in `service.xml`, that might be the problem since you are getting:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Column employerCity not found,
```

may be you are referencing this column incorrectly in some entity or I would suggest check the spelling of the column.

Answer (score 0):

Inside lib you have--->/HelloPortlet-portlet/docroot/WEB-INF/lib/HelloPortlet-portlet-service.jar
Delete the above jar in your project
    After changes done in your service.xml build services again and refresh
    Goto database check your table if it is not there refresh once you can see according to your modified service.xml.